# Even with ASP.NET 3.5, I am getting "Validation of viewstate MAC failed" error

Tags: asp.net-3.5

I found a lost of posts to solve this error: "Validation of viewstate MAC failed". I read that it is a ASP.NET 2.0 error which is also a bug. But I am using VS 2008 with ASP.NET 3.5 SP1. Why this error is coming in this version also?

I am using ASP TextBox controls. Some posts have mentioned that ASP TextBoxes generate this error, so I have set AutoPostBack of each TextBox to False.

How to get rid of this mess?

Code Added Below **

*** Default.aspx ***

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="FlexStock._Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <!--<%@ Register Assembly="MSCaptcha" Namespace="MSCaptcha" TagPrefix="cc1" %>-->
    <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Styles/main.css" />
    <title>FlexStock@.NET - Gamma Edition</title>
</head>
<body id="LoginPageBody" class="loginPageBodyClass">
<img id="imgProductLogo" src="Styles/stockist_gamma.png" style="text-align:center;text-shadow:black;margin-left:500px" alt="Product Logo"/>
    <form id="loginForm" runat="server" class="loginForm" action="./Forms/selectCompany.aspx" >
    <div id="divMainLoginPage" runat="server">
        <div class="label">
            <asp:Label ID="lblUserName" runat="server" CssClass="LabelControls" AssociatedControlID="txtUserName">User Name: </asp:Label>     
        </div>

        <div class="value">
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtUserName" runat="server" CssClass="TxtStyle" Width="199px" AutoPostBack="false"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>

        <div class="label">
            <asp:Label ID="lblPassword" runat="server" CssClass="LabelControls" AssociatedControlID="txtPassword">Password: </asp:Label>     
        </div>

        <div class="value">
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" runat="server" CssClass="TxtStyle" TextMode="Password" Width="199px" AutoPostBack="false"></asp:TextBox>        
        </div>

        <div class="label">
            <asp:Label ID="lblCaptcha" runat="server" Text="Security Check"></asp:Label>
        </div>

        <div class="value">
           <!-- <cc1:CaptchaControl ID="ccJoin" runat="server" CaptchaBackgroundNoise="none" CaptchaLength="5" CaptchaHeight="60" CaptchaWidth="200" CaptchaLineNoise="None" CaptchaMinTimeout="5" CaptchaMaxTimeout="240" />  -->
        </div>

        <div class="label">
            <asp:Label ID="lblEnterCaptcha" runat="server" Text="Enter Value"></asp:Label>
        </div>

        <div class="value">
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtCaptcha" runat="server" CssClass="TxtStyle" Width="199px" AutoPostBack="false"></asp:TextBox><br /><br />
            <asp:Button ID="btnLogin" runat="server" Width="60" Text="Login" CssClass="BtnStyle"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
    <img id="img1" src="Styles/impact_logo.png" style="text-align:right;text-shadow:black;margin-left:800px" />
</body>
</html>
```

selectCompany.aspx **

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/master1.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="~/Forms/selectCompany.aspx.cs" Inherits="FlexStock.Forms.selectCompany" EnableViewStateMac="false" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
    <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../Styles/selectCompany.css" />
    <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../Styles/main.css" /> 

</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

   <form id="frmSelectCompany" enableviewstate="false">
        <div id="label" class="label" style="width:300px">
            <asp:Label ID="lblSelectCompany" runat="server" Text="Select Company or Create New"></asp:Label>
        </div>
        <div id="btnCreate" style="text-align:right">
            <asp:Button ID="btnCreateNew" runat="server" Text="Create New" CssClass="BtnStyle" />
        </div><br />

        <div id="divGrid">
        </div>

    </form>

</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty common error to see. It's a security feature in ASP.NET that prevents someone from injecting additional controls onto the page after it has rendered, and posting those controls back to the server. It makes your website harder to hack.

Are you creating any input controls through javascript? If so, don't. Create the controls normally inside the web form and wrap them in a `<div style='display:none;'>` and display them when you need them.

Are you creating any controls dynamically within C#? - If you are, you must create them inside `Page_Init`, not `Page_Load`, otherwise ASP.NET won't recognise them as valid.

You can disable this security measure by setting `EnableViewStateMac=False` at the top of the aspx page, but I strongly advise against it.

Comment: I have a Captcha control on Default.aspx. When I press Login button on this Form, it gives error while opening the other Form.

Comment: @RPK Hard to tell without seeing the code. If you create a test page with only the Captcha and Button, does it postback without error?

Comment: I disabled the Captcha altogether but still got error. When I added EnableViewStateMac = False, it worked. But you say it is not recommended. Than what? Pasting code in my OP.

Comment: @RPK The problem is that you are posting to selectCompany.aspx from the default.aspx page. Typically ASP.NET pages should post back to themselves, which explains the error. Remove the `action` from the form. Create a button handler to catch the btnLogin_Click event, place your login validation code here and perform a 'Response.Redirect("SelectCompany.aspx")` if the login was successful.